# How To Pull JSON Data Using PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to create a very simple php script that can pull data from a JSON file (array?) and echo it to the page. Sadly, I'm a complete newbie when it comes to PHP.

My goal is to dump all IP addresses and the corresponding client version into an output like this...

```
"127.0.0.1" "/Satoshi:0.9.1/" 
"127.0.0.2" "/Satoshi:0.9.0/"
"127.0.0.3" "/Satoshi:0.9.0/"
"127.0.0.4" "/Satoshi:0.9.1/"
```

I can get the code to dump all data, but I'm not sure how to pull the ip and version without the ip and client version being named.. If that even makes sense?

Here is the code. What do I need to make it dump the correct data?

```
<?php
$url = 'https://getaddr.bitnodes.io/nodes/1407675714.json';
$JSON = file_get_contents($url);

echo $JSON;

$data = json_decode($JSON);
var_dump($data);

?>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Show us the current var dump

Comment: it looks like an array of arrays. use a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop to iterate over the main array and return the keys that you want from each sub-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
<?php
$url = 'https://getaddr.bitnodes.io/nodes/1407675714.json';
$JSON = file_get_contents($url);

$data = json_decode($JSON);
$data = (array)$data; // cast from stdClass to array, as results have int keys

foreach($data['nodes'] as $results){
    echo $results[0]. " ". $results[3]."<br />";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't makes much sense to convert an array of hashes into the one of some non-named entities. I guess that all you need is to dump it in the following way:

```
    foreach($data as $t)
    {
            echo("ip=".$t->ip." ua=".$t->ua);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any reason to cast to an array. Just process the returned object. This one has the double quotes as requested as well.

```
<?php
  $url = 'https://getaddr.bitnodes.io/nodes/1407675714.json';
  $json = file_get_contents($url);

  $data = json_decode($json);

  foreach($data->nodes as $results){
      echo "\"".$results[0]."\" \"".$results[3]."\"<br />";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Mark, thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question and providing me with the correct code - it's much appreciated!